# Missing Values After Applying Mask Function

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a raster called 'xx' and is the output from using the 'Distance' function within R Raster. As part of running the distance function, the ocean/sea surrounding my island has been set to a value of 0. In order to change this value from 0 back to NA, I have used the function 'Mask' like so:

```
asdf<-mask(xx,jamaica.raster, filename="distancesurface.asc", prj=TRUE, keepres=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)
```

In the above example, jamaica.raster is being used to replace the 0 values with NA. I run the command and plot the result. As expected, it has left my distance surface in place and set the ocean to NA, exactly as I wanted.

After, when I attempt to writeRaster the object 'asdf' I get the error:

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
>     Couldn't find data values in ASCII Grid file.

If I get a summary of the objects 'xx' and 'jamaica.raster' before applying 'mask' function, both have a 'values' section like so:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 135, 306, 41310  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -78.49359, -75.94359, 17.59729, 18.72229  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
data source : D:\Dropbox\\... 
names       : jamaicapc1 
values      : -3.419589, 14.17305  (min, max)
```

If I do the same for my new object 'asdf' there are no values- They seem to have gone missing since using the Mask function. For example:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 135, 306, 41310  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -78.49359, -75.94359, 17.59729, 18.72229  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
data source : C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\distancesurface.asc 
names       : distancesurface
```

I assume this is expected behaviour so my question is, how can I write my new raster (asdf) to disk? Is there a step I need to carry out before I can use the writeRaster function?

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: By passing the `filename` argument to `mask`, a file should already be created for you at `distancesurface.asc`. Is it not?

Comment: Hi jbaums, I've been dumping everything to my desktop as a scratch disk and it just wasn't appearing there. I've just restarted my computer and changed the directory and the raster is now appearing :)

I'm running an insider build of Windows 10 on my personal laptop at the moment- I think it must have been some kind of bug. Lesson learnt though- don't use preview software when you need to do real work!